# How to add event handlers to DIVS with CSS classes containing a particular string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to be able to add some onclick event handlers to some DIV elements which are styled by CSS classes matching a particular string.  The DIVS would be for a particular type of image which represents something called a Work Center in Discrete Event Simulation that I want users to be able to click on, change some settings, and run the simulation again.

I'm using a system that was developed ages ago that handles these images like so:

```
<div id="Decision__1" class="S8DisplayObject Image__for__Decision__1" style="top:35px; left:579px; width:118px; height:71px;"><div id="Decision__1_textData_2" class="S8Web-TextData" style="left:-136px; top:-12px;"><div class="noTextWrap">0</div></div><div class="sb_block_display"></div></div>
<div id="Decision__2" class="S8DisplayObject Image__for__Decision__2" style="top:35px; left:579px; width:118px; height:71px;"><div id="Decision__2_textData_2" class="S8Web-TextData" style="left:-136px; top:-12px;"><div class="noTextWrap">0</div></div><div class="sb_block_display"></div></div>
```

So it incrementally assigns a number to each class, and in this case, the string I would want to compare would be `Image__for__Decision`.  Unfortunately I can't really delve into how these CSS classes are named, as they are part of a much larger conversion process.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "[attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)" selector:

```
$("div[class*='Image__for__Decision']").click(function() {
    console.log("click!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

James beat me to the punch, but I think for this I prefer the ["starts-with"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

```
var yourDivs = $("div[class^='Image__for__Decision']");
```

His code also shows how you can set up the event handler.

Comment: This won't work in this case, because the attribute selector treats the entire value of the `class` attribute as one value, not separate classes, and the string does not start with `Image__for_Decision` (it's the second class in the list of classes).

Comment: After a quick test, I stand corrected.  Thanks for that, and I withdraw.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageDivs = $('div[class*="Image_for_Decision"]');
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)